# MIPS Caching: Why write to lower level cache when data is evicted, since its already outdated

Tags: caching, mips

I am confused why is data from upper level cache written to lower level when its evicted, since it is already outdated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is evicted when data from another address maps to the same cache index and way. If the data that was originally in the cache line was modified, then the modified data needs to be written to memory so that the modification is not lost.

Example: for a 4k byte direct-mapped cache, address 0 and address 4096 both map to the same location in the cache, so if address 0 is modified and then address 4096 is modified, the modified data at address 0 must be written back to memory before the modified data for address 4096 can be stored in the cache.  If address 0 did not contain modified data, then nothing needs to be written back to memory before modified data for address 4096 can be stored in the cache.